# Laravel - How to handle errors on PUT form?

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am working with laravel 5.2 and want to validate some data in an edit form. I goal should be to display the errors and keep the wrong data in the input fields.

My issue is that the input is validated by `ContentRequest` and the `FormRequest` returns

```
$this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
```

which is fine so far. Next step the `edit` action in the controller is called and all parameters are overwritten.

What I have currently done:

**ContentController**:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $content = Content::find($id);

    return view('contents.edit', ['content' => $content]);
}

public function update(ContentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $content = Content::find($id);

    foreach (array_keys(array_except($this->fields, ['content'])) as $field) {
        $content->$field = $request->get($field);
    }
    $content->save();

    return redirect(URL::route('manage.contents.edit', array('content' => $content->id)))
        ->withSuccess("Changes saved.");
}
```

**ContentRequest**:

```
class ContentRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'body' => 'required|min:3'
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? The form looks like this:

```
<form action="{!! URL::route('manage.contents.update', array('content' => $content->slug)) !!}"
          id="site-form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
        {!! method_field('PUT') !!}
        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title"
                       value="{{ $content->title }}">

                @if ($errors->has('title'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: How did you construct the form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```php
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
name="title"
id="title"
placeholder="Title"
value="{{ old('title', $content->title) }}" />
```

Note the `value` attribute. Also [check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input) and find `Retrieving Old Data`.

Comment: Thanks, that the solution